# How to replace strings in a DataFrame column using priority based regex?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of a DataFrame that has manually entered job titles. There are hundreds but I want to reduce them down to the following buckets

```
CXO or Senior Vice President
Vice President
Director
Manager
etc...
```

Some of the job titles have multiple actual titles like "CEO and Director of Marketing" or "Vice President and Software Engineer" so I would like to replace with the highest ranked bucket. Here's what I've done so far (which is not working).

```
skip_jobs=[]
df['jobtitle'].replace(to_replace='.*[Cc].[Oo].*|.*[Vv]ice.*', value='CXO or Senior Vice President,
    regex=True, inplace=True)
skip_jobs.append('CXO or Senior Vice President')

df['jobtitle'][~df['jobtitle'].isin(skip_jobs)].replace(to_replace='.*VP*|.*[Vv]ice.*',
    value='Vice President', regex=True, inplace=True)
...
```

One problem is that regex=True means that both to_replace and value are treated as regex so any patterns that I match are replaced with the value treated as a regex. I want the entire string to be replaced with a new string - ex: "CEO and Director of Marketing" to be replaced with "CXO or Senior Vice President". If anyone has some ideas let me know, thank you.

edit: How to label remaining jobs as 'Other'? Below is what I'm currently using but it's overwriting some of the previous jobs as other.

```
skip_jobs = ['CXO or Sen. Vice Pres', 'Vice President'...]
df['jobtitle'][~df['jobtitle'].isin(skip_jobs)] = 'Other'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `replace` method under `str` is easier to use. You mighe have to modify the regex in my code to fit your data, but just remember to match the whole string.

```
>>> df['title']
0                  CXO or Senior Vice President
1                                Vice President
2                                           CEO
3                                       Manager

>>> df['title'] = df['title'].str.replace('^.*(C[A-Z]O|VP|[Vv]ice).*$', 'CXO or Senior Vice President')

>>> df['title']
0    CXO or Senior Vice President
1    CXO or Senior Vice President
2    CXO or Senior Vice President
3                         Manager
```

Comment: Oh ok, yeah this works. How would I go about taking any job title not found in my list of job titles and setting them to 'Other'? This is what I currently have and it's overwriting too many values as 'Other'. Edit: i can't add code to this, I updated my original post. Thank you for your comment btw!

Comment: you can use either str.contains or str.match method to find out whether the string match your regex, then assign the matches to whatever you want and so to the others